# What is the name of the Feminist Zionist Atheist woman who was interviewed on BBC on June 15th 2018?

Tags: ideology, geopolitics, zionism

Was able to listen to the last moments of an interview on a BBC radio program on June 15th shortly before midnight with a woman who identified herself as a "Jewish atheist" while describing how Zionist leaders had come to the conclusion that no "messiah" was going to come to help the Jewish people who had designs to form their own nation state and further that if the Zionists intended to have their own nation state they would have to do the work themselves without awaiting help from a deity.

Edited to add: Found the program [BBC World Service - Weekend, Fri 15 June, 2018](https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/w172w71sbnxm1rz) beginning at 8:55. Am unable to discern her name spoken on the program, but it was pronounced like "Inette Wolf"? The media at the link does not provide Closed Captioning. She was evidently a member of the Israeli government at some point.

Who is this woman?

Comment: You don't know the programme you were listening to or even the station? Also midnight where? UK time? The schedules are still up. https://www.bbc.co.uk/schedules/p00fzl7j/2018/06/15

Comment: @MartinSmith No, was only able to catch the last portion of the interview, or words spoken by the individual. Will try the link that you provided.

Comment: @MartinSmith The link to "Midnight News" navigates to a "Sign in" form. The time was close to but before midnight U.S. time. The individual sounded outspoken; that that was not the first interview that she had given; that she might possibly be a well-recognized author and/or (jewish atheist) political activist in isreal.

Comment: *Which* midnight US time? The United States have 6 different timezones. And does anyone from [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Jewish_atheists_and_agnostics) ring a bell? Yes, I know it's a long list, but if you filter it down to living women, then there aren't actually that many who remain.

Comment: @Philipp Read the linked list before viewing your comment; could not locate the individual am trying to identify. Did preliminary research before asking the question here. The timezone should not matter. The program was being aired before midnight. Yes, the woman is living. Not entirely certain that the woman herself was being interviewed, or if she was simply commenting on the topic of "jewish atheists" or "athesist jews". There some some indication that the woman had been either a political activist or author. Was only able to hear approximately one minute of her talk.

Comment: @agc It was a radio program, no visual observations were made. She sounded to be in her 30's-50's, though that is only an estimate. Her accent was not U.S. or British english. The host of the program was a woman with a British accent, who closed the segment stating roughly that they were sure that they would be hearing from the woman again.

Comment: @guest271314, D'oh, missed the word *"radio"*, sorry.  After going to the site noted in [*Martin Smith*'s comment](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/31581/what-is-the-name-of-the-jewish-atheist-woman-whom-was-interviewed-on-bbc-on-june#comment116819_31581), I notice that in one episode the news is read by a female newsreader and in another by a male -- if the newsreader's gender can be recalled it may eliminate some episodes.

Comment: @agc See previous comment. The host was a woman with a British accent.  The pure facts are that the time was between 11:30PM and 12:00AM Friday June 16, 2018, broadcast on an NPR (National Public Radio) affiliate. It is possible that the program was not actually a BBC (British Broadcasting Corporation) program, though to the best of recollection BBC was mentioned.

Comment: @Philipp Found the program [BBC World Service - Weekend, Fri 15 June, 2018](https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/w172w71sbnxm1rz) beginning at 8:55. Am unable to discern her name spoken on the program, "Inette Wolf"? The media at the link does not provide Closed Captioning. She was evidently a member of the Isreali government at some point.

Comment: "close" voters, kindly explain how this question is "off-topic" [Help Center > Asking](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (in pertinent part) _"3. Conflicting Egos:

In just about any policy of substance, there are particular personalities that are central to its understanding, as well as demographic data about supporters and opponents of legislation."_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Einat Wilf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einat_Wilf):

> is an Israeli politician who served as a member of the Knesset for Independence and the Labor Party... ...Wilf describes herself as a Zionist and an atheist.